# Can't open Nautilus Windows from external programs on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: nautilus, gnome-shell, 18.10

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 and yesterday I ran a  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`  as soon as I first booted.

Then, I tried using File Roller to extract a .tar.gz and the window just turned dark (as if it weren't responding) and I couldn't close it from itself or from the Gnome dock. I didn't gave it much thought and carried on with my day with that window still open and Nautilus working just fine when executed from the Dock Icon out from a terminal.

Later, I was installing Calibre (e-book management software) version 3.40.1 using it's default binary install (https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) and tried adding a book to my library. The program opened a Zenity window with a broken icon that couldn't be opened from the gnome dock, but hovering over it I could see it was a Nautilus window.

My guess is that Nautilus is not able to open itself from external programs and would like to know if anyone else ever had that problem, because googling was insufficient. Sorry about the lack of screenshots, I'm away from home and can post them later

EDIT: I reisntalled Calibre via apt, so the version is older than the one from the site's binary install. Still, it did not work properly.

Output of `apt-cache policy nautilus calibre file-roller`:

```
nautilus:
  Instalado: 1:3.26.4-0ubuntu7.1
  Candidato: 1:3.26.4-0ubuntu7.1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 1:3.26.4-0ubuntu7.1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.26.4-0ubuntu7 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
calibre:
  Instalado: 3.31.0+dfsg-1
  Candidato: 3.31.0+dfsg-1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 3.31.0+dfsg-1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
file-roller:
  Instalado: 3.30.1-1
  Candidato: 3.30.1-1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 3.30.1-1 500
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `nautilus --version`:
`GNOME nautilus 3.26.4`

Output of `which nautilus`:
`/usr/bin/nautilus`

Output of `file-roller --version`:
`file-roller 3.30.1, Copyright © 2001-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Output of `which file-roller`:
`/usr/bin/file-roller`

Output of `calibre --version`:
`calibre (calibre 3.31)`

Output of `which calibre`:
`/usr/bin/calibre`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Nautilus was opening as expected, but in the desktop of my second monitor, which was shut off this whole time. I'm not very smart.